# Unable to send multiple emails in BCCs using Sendgrid API for ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: email, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am working on a ASP.NET Core WebAPI where I am using SendGrid to send emails. Earlier, I was able to use the helper class CreateSingleEmail to send a single mail to a single recipient.
Now, I wish to send the same email to multiple recipient in BCC so, the recipients are not able to see the other recipients.
I have gone through many documentation on this issue and even the previous similar issues raised for this but I am still unable to send the mails.
I have tried to use Personalization block too. I do not get any error per se but emails are not being sent through this.
Here is my method-

Please note that here, toEmail is of type List.

```
       var apiKey = "MySendgridApiKey"
        var client = new 
        SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage();
        msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress(fromEmail));
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(fromEmail), 1);
        msg.SetBypassListManagement(true);
        msg.SetBccSetting(true, fromEmail);
        msg.AddSubstitution("%name1%", "Example User1");
        msg.SetSubject(subject);
        var personalization = new Personalization()
        {
            Bccs = toEmail  
        };
        msg.AddBccs(toEmail);
        msg.AddBccs(toEmail, 0, personalization);
        msg.Serialize();
        var response = client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        return true;
```

Technical details:
Platform ( ASP.NET Core WebAPI)
.NET Core Version: 2.0.8

Answer (score 0):

You are already using

```
msg.AddBccs(toEmail);
```

That also takes a `List<SendGridMessage>`. So just pass in all email addresses as list here.

Comment: Thank you @Nopeman. Here, toEmail is type of list only that I am passing.